# Control CSP of an Iframe calling JS

Tags: javascript, magento, iframe, content-security-policy, braintree

I have an e-commerce site calling a iframe https://assets.braintreegateway.com/web/3.85.5/html/hosted-fields-frame.min.html

This in turn is calling https://c.paypal.com/da/r/fb.js.

I am getting the below error in my browser console when going to my e-commerce site.

[image]

https://assets.braintreegateway.com/web/3.85.5/html/hosted-fields-frame.min.html has the below CSP defined:

```
content-security-policy: style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.braintreegateway.com *.braintree-api.com;
```

while the e-commerce site (still in development) has:

```
content-security-policy: script-src http: https: 'unsafe-inline';
```

Should I be whitelisting `c.paypal.com` in my CSP? I sort of expect Braintree to whitelist but well Braintree is Paypal company so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a misconfiguration by Braintree. You can't allow anything in an ancestor CSP to allow something that is not allowed in the CSP of the framed page.